# How do I pronounce the Swedish "o": /ʊ uː/ or /ɔ oː/?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, swedish

I'm a Swedish learner. As a beginner in Swedish, I thought the Swedish "o" was pronounced /o oː/. However, recently, I read the Wikipedia article ["Swedish phonology"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_phonology), and I noticed that there are two pronunciations of the Swedish "o": /ʊ uː/, and /ɔ oː/. When is the Swedish "o" pronounced /ʊ uː/, and when is the Swedish "o" pronounced /ɔ oː/? Examples of both pronunciations: 
 
/ʊ uː/: 
"kr**o**na": [ˈkruːˌna] 
"b**o**k": [buːk] 
"**o**rd": [ˈuːɖ] 
 
/ɔ oː/: 
"**o**ch": [ɔ] 
"s**o**m": [sɔm] 
"k**o**pp": [kɔp] 
"N**o**rge": [ˈnɔrjɛ] 
 
How do I know if the Swedish "o" is pronounced /ʊ uː/ or /ɔ oː/? Does it depend on the following consonant? Thank you.